# Как отправлять письма с удаленного сервера?

Tags: php, хостинг

Пользуюсь OpenServer, там с помощью функции `mail()` отправляю сообщения администратору на `email`

```html
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_fs', 'mig_mail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fs', 'mig_mail');

function mig_mail (){
    $recepient = get_bloginfo('admin_email');

    $siteName = get_bloginfo();

    $data = urldecode($_POST['data']);
    parse_str( $data, $arr );

    $name     = !empty($arr['name'])   ? "Имя: "       . trim($arr['name'])   . "\n" : "";
    $tel      = !empty($arr['phone'])  ? "Телефон: +"  . trim($arr['phone'])  . "\n" : "";
    $email    = !empty($arr['email'])  ? "Email: "     . trim($arr['email'])  . "\n" : "";
    $text     = !empty($arr['review']) ? "Сообщение: " . trim($arr['review']) . "\n" : "";

    if (empty($text)){
        $pageTitle = "Заявка с сайта \"$siteName\"";
    } else {
        $pageTitle = "Отзыв с сайта \"$siteName\"";
    }


    $message = "$name$tel$email$text";

    mail(
        $recepient,
        $pageTitle,
        $message,
        "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient"
    );

    wp_die();
}
```

На OpenServer работает. Закинул на хостинг сайт. Загрузил файлы, базу данных. Отправка сообщений не работает.
Как настраивать отправку на удаленном сервере?

Comment: Спросите в службе поддержки хостера, а то может mail() заблокирована, чтобы спам не рассылали.

Comment: В первую очередь попробуйте использовать wp_mail(). Эта функция является обёрткой mail() и специально создана для обхода проблемных ситуаций, которые могут возникнуть на хостингах.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Действительно, нужно было исправить mail() на wp_mail(). Можете сделать это ответом, я помечу как правильный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первую очередь попробуйте использовать wp_mail(). Эта функция является обёрткой mail() и специально создана для обхода проблемных ситуаций, которые могут возникнуть на хостингах.